# Error learning with perceptron 1 Layer

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I need help with my perceptron 1 layer, I use a function sigmoide to transfert function and the algorithme back propagate for the learning. I want to do a simple neural network for compute A and B(logical and). My problem is after the learning i put 2 value (for exemple 0 and 0) and my IA give me always 0.99. I see the code 3 times and I don't understand why my programme return bad answer after learning. Please help me.

Neuron.java :

```
public class Neuron {
  public double value;
  public double[] weights;
  public double bias;
  public double deltas;

public Neuron(int nb_entree){
    weights = new double[nb_entree];

    value =  Math.random() / 10000000000000.0;
    bias = Math.random() / 10000000000000.0;
    deltas = Math.random() / 10000000000000.0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < weights.length ; i++){
        weights[i] = Math.random() / 10000000000000.0;
    }
}

/***
 * Function to evaluate a neurone with a sigmoide function
 * @param input : list to input value
 * @return the result of sigmoide function
 */
public double evaluate(double[] input){
    double x = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length ; i++){
        x += input[i] * weights[i];
    }
    x += bias;

    value = 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, x));

    return value;
}

//Function to delete value of neurons
protected void delete(){
    value = 0.0;
}
}
```

NeuralNetwork.java :

```
public class NeuralNetwork {
  public Neuron[] neurons_hidden;
  public Neuron[] neurons_output;
  public double rate_learning;
  public int nb_hidden;
  public int nb_output;

public NeuralNetwork(int nb_input, int nb_hid, int nb_out, double rate){
    nb_hidden = nb_hid;
    nb_output = nb_out;
    rate_learning = rate;

    neurons_hidden = new Neuron[nb_hidden];
    neurons_output = new Neuron[nb_output];

    //Create hidden neurons
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_hidden ; i++){
        neurons_hidden[i] = new Neuron(nb_input);
    }

    //Create output neurons
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_output ; i++){
        neurons_output[i] = new Neuron(nb_hidden);
    }
}

public double[] evaluate(double[] input){
    double[] output_hidden = new double[nb_hidden];
    double[] outputs = new double[nb_output];

    //we delete the value of hidden neurons
    for(Neuron n : neurons_hidden){
        n.delete();
    }

    //we delete the value of output neurons
    for(Neuron n : neurons_output){
        n.delete();
    }

    //Pour chaque neurone caches
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_hidden ; i++){
        output_hidden[i] = neurons_hidden[i].evaluate(input);   
    }

    //Pour chaque neurone sortie
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_output ; i++){
        outputs[i] = neurons_output[i].evaluate(output_hidden);
    }

    return outputs;
}


public double backPropagate(double[] input, double[] output){

    double[] output_o = evaluate(input);
    double error;
    int i;
    int k;

    //For all neurons output, we compute the deltas
    for(i = 0 ; i < nb_output ; i++){
            error = output[i] - output_o[i];
            neurons_output[i].deltas = error * (output_o[i] - Math.pow(output_o[i], 2));
    }

    //For all neurons hidden, we compute the deltas
    for(i = 0 ; i < nb_hidden ; i++){
        error = 0.0;
        for(k = 0 ; k < nb_output ; k++){
            error += neurons_output[k].deltas * neurons_output[k].weights[i];
        }
        neurons_hidden[i].deltas = error * (neurons_hidden[i].value - Math.pow(neurons_hidden[i].value, 2));            
    }


    //For all neurons output, we modify the weight
    for(i = 0 ; i < nb_output ; i++){
        for(k = 0 ; k <  nb_hidden ; k++){
            neurons_output[i].weights[k] += rate_learning * 
                                                neurons_output[i].deltas * 
                                                    neurons_hidden[k].value;
        }
        neurons_output[i].bias += rate_learning * neurons_output[i].deltas;
    }


    //For all neurons hidden, we modify the weight
    for(i = 0 ; i < nb_hidden ; i++){
        for(k = 0 ; k < input.length ; k++){
            neurons_hidden[i].weights[k] += rate_learning * neurons_hidden[i].deltas * input[k];        
        }
        neurons_hidden[i].bias += rate_learning * neurons_hidden[i].deltas;
    }

    error = 0.0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < output.length ; i++){
        error += Math.abs(output_o[i] - output[i]);
    }

    error = error / output.length;

    return error;
}
}
```

Test.java :

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NeuralNetwork net = new NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1, 0.6);

    /* Learning */
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++)
    {   
        double[] inputs = new double[]{Math.round(Math.random()), Math.round(Math.random())};
        double[] output = new double[1];
        double error;

        if((inputs[0] == inputs[1]) && (inputs[0] == 1))
            output[0] = 1.0;
        else
            output[0] = 0.0;

        System.out.println(inputs[0]+" and "+inputs[1]+" = "+output[0]);

        error = net.backPropagate(inputs, output);
        System.out.println("Error at step "+i+" is "+error);
    }

    System.out.println("Learning finish!");

    /* Test */
    double[] inputs = new double[]{0.0, 0.0};
    double[] output = net.evaluate(inputs);

    System.out.println(inputs[0]+" and "+inputs[1]+" = "+output[0]+""); 
}
}
```

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 0):

Your sigmoid function is not correct. It needs a negative t:

```
1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -x))
```

I am not sure if that is the only mistake.

Additionally, for the connective "and" you need only one layer.

Finally, you treat your bias separately in your back propagation method. That can be simplified by adding an input node with a constant 1 as input and the bias as weight. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Definitions.